# Wifi connection problems with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

Ever since I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 I have had wifi connection problems.  It's just got much worse now, though.  I have managed to get a wifi connection and successfully used Ping 8.8.8.8 to check that it is working O.K. and it is.  However, I can't get Firefox browser to open, nor get Updater to connect, as always get "no wifi connection" message.  I am using BT wifi and rt61pci.  Can someone, please, help me? Thanks.

Output for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` is as follows:

```
03:02.0 Network Contoller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT2561/RT61 802.11g PCI [1814:0301]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RT2561/RT61 802.11g PCI [1462:834]
    Kernel driver in use:rt61pci
    Kernel modules: rt61pci
```

What I need help with, please, is how to get wifi connection up and running again on my PC.  I have been through all the suggestions in the Troubleshooting Guide and still can't get the wifi connection to work.  What is puzzling for me is that the network icon says that I am connected to the BT wifi and the signal is strong and I can alsprove that wifi connis live, as I get positive messages though using Ping 8.8.8.8.  However, whenever I try to access the Firefox browser or Software Updater, I get a message on the screen that says there is no wifi connection!  I am not really that skilled in IT issues and would welcome any guidance to help me access the Internet through wifi on my PC.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Output for lspci -inn | grep Net -A3 is as follows:

Comment: PLEASE DON'T POST IT TO COMMENTS!!!

Comment: Instead please use the [edit] button to edit your question and add the additional information. Then let Pilot6 know in the comments that you have added this information to the question.

Comment: Question now edited with output from suggested command.

Answer (score 0):

you may try resetting the modem to **factory default** and **REINSTALL it with the disc you got when bought it** and sync it with your device using **LAN**